# Group multiple options to dataclass/pydantic objects

Tags: python, python-click

Is it possible with python-click library to define options in such way that they are converted to a dataclass (or pydantic). For example, I have to enable operation on remote host, meaning I need hostname, username, password and port:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Host(BaseModel):
    username: str = getlogin()
    password: Optional[str] = None
    address: str = 'localhost'
    port: int = 22
```

Now, my options may be defined like:

```
@remote_tools.command(name='remote', help='Execute command remote', context_settings=dict(max_content_width=120))
@click.option('-a', '--address', help='Remote host address')
@click.option('-o', '--port', help='Remote host address port')
@click.option('-u', '--username', help='Remote host address username')
@click.option('-p', '--password', help='Remote host address password')
def command(address: str, port: int, username: str, password: str):
    host = Host(address=address, port=port, username=username, password=password)
    print(host)
```

Is there a way to make it look like:

```
@remote_tools.command(name='remote', help='Execute command remote', context_settings=dict(max_content_width=120))
@click.option('-a', '--address', help='Remote host address')
@click.option('-o', '--port', help='Remote host address port')
@click.option('-u', '--username', help='Remote host address username')
@click.option('-p', '--password', help='Remote host address password')
def command(host: Host):
    print(host)
```

Or in perfect case:

```
@remote_tools.command(name='remote', help='Execute command remote', context_settings=dict(max_content_width=120))
@click.option('-h', '--host', help='Remote host')
def command(host: Host):
    print(host)
```

If last one is possible, how to define help message per field?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm following in case someone has any clever ideas, but unfortunately I suspect it's ultimately a feature request. (But a good one!)